# How to convert s3EventRecord from AWS SNS to map (Go)

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

My data flow is as follows:

1. File is uploaded to s3 bucket
2. s3 bucket triggers SNS topic
3. SNS topic passes s3 event as a message to lambda
4. Lambda is triggered by SNS and attempts to read record.SNS.Message
5. I try to convert the message (escaped JSON) to map for easy parsing.

I tried to do like strconv.Unquote but that didn't work. How do I unmarshal this string? Here is my relevant code:

```
func Handler(request events.SNSEvent) {
    for _, record := range request.Records {
        message := record.SNS.Message
        x := make(map[string]string)
        jsonErr := json.Unmarshal([]byte(message),&x)
        if jsonErr!=nil {
            logger.Errorf("Welp couldn't convert json to a map %s",jsonErr.Error())
        }
```

Comment: Rule of thumb for `json.Unmarshal` is to create dedicated structure that reflects payload.

Comment: I see. What should be my proper way to approach this problem then? I'd rather not create another struct but if I have to then I will I guess.

Comment: It is normal for strong type language to have definition of every structure you use.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, that structure exists in `github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events`. Instead of *unmarshaling* into a map, use the `s3Event` struct.

This is how I use this:

```
    for _, snsEventRecord := range event.Records {
    var s3Event events.S3Event
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(snsEventRecord.SNS.Message), &s3Event)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for _, s3EventRecord := range s3Event.Records {
        fmt.Println(s3EventRecord.S3.Object.Key)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Follow up:

More on `json.Unmarshal` can be found in excellent examples here:
https://gobyexample.com/json